Mocking Exceptions in Nest.js e2e Testing
I am learning Nest.js and currently working on e2e testing.I was reading some online blogs and learned about Mocking API responses / Exceptions. I have written some tests and with mocking they work fine. But since I am still a beginner with this framework, I am kind of lost.
My user.e2e-spec.ts looks like this
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserController } from '../src/user/user.controller';
import { UserService } from '../src/user/user.service';
import { BadRequestException, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from '../src/user/dto/create-user.dto/create-user.dto';

describe('UserController', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  const userService = {
    create: jest.fn(),
    findAll: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    update: jest.fn(),
    remove: jest.fn(),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [], // Replace with actual UserModule import
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: userService }],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    // await app.close();
  });

  //Tests

  it('/POST users (Create User)', () => {
    const newUserData: CreateUserDto = {
      username: 'testuser',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      password: 'password',
    };
    userService.create.mockReturnValue(
      Promise.resolve({ ...newUserData, _id: 1 }),
    );

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/users')
      .send(newUserData)
      .expect({
        status: 201,
        message: 'User created successfully',
        data: { _id: 1, ...newUserData },
      });
  });

  it('/POST users - Validation Error - No Username', async () => {
    const invalidUserData = { email: 'test@email.com', password: '1234' }; // Missing username

    const err = new BadRequestException({
      statusCode: 400,
      error: 'Bad Request',
      message: ['username should not be empty', 'username must be a string'],
    });
    userService.create.mockRejectedValue(err);

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/users')
      .send(invalidUserData)
      .expect({
        statusCode: 400,
        error: 'Bad Request',
        message: ['username should not be empty', 'username must be a string'],
      });
  });
});

This is the exact same response I receive when I test the API in Postman,

I tried catching them and the error message is similar, using following configuration in test environment setup.
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    whitelist: true,
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    transform: true,
    exceptionFactory: (validationErrors = []) => {
      const simplifiedMessages = validationErrors.flatMap(err => {
        // Map each constraint in the errors to a cleaner format without repeating the property name
        return Object.values(err.constraints).map((message) => {
          // Optionally remove the property name from the start of the message if desired
          return message.replace(`${err.property} `, '');
        });
      });
      return new BadRequestException({
        statusCode: 400,
        error: 'Bad Request',
        message: simplifiedMessages,
      });
    },
  }),
);

Although the first approach seems very simple and straight-forward, I am a bit confused though, is this the correct way of testing the routes? Or should I be catching the actual error messages sent by the application instead?
Its been only a week since I started working with Nest.js so my explanation may not be very precise. Please let me know if this needs further clarification.
